# Call to functionality over and over again

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've node application which is calling to some logger functionality.
I call to this code in every module (instead of console.log)

**my question**
I dont like it... There a better way to do that in Node.js? 
instead of calling to the **declaration** (the following first 3 lines)here over and over again
it seems that this is redundend code which will be called in every module which I need to use this logger(almost all...)

```
var Logs = require("internal-logging");
var appCon = Logs.addContext();
var logger = appCon.getLogger("/app/run");

...

//this is the call to the logger inside each module

 logger.info("Configuration was found: " + path);
```

Comment: You can use `EventEmitter` and create in one place event-listener, which will be logging messages, and in other modules just emit your custom event for logging and pass to it needed message

Comment: @MysterX - can you please provide example how to do that?

Comment: Have you considered putting all this in one line? `var logger = require("internal-logging").addContext().getLogger("/app/run");`? Doesn't look like you could shorten that much more.

Comment: May be you can create a module add these lines to that module and include it in single line where ever you require ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own logger module:

```
// my-logger.js
var Logs = require("internal-logging");
var appCon = Logs.addContext();
var logger = appCon.getLogger("/app/run");
module.exports = logger;
```

And then in your other files:

```
var logger = require("./my-logger");
```